NODEJS Lambda function has "EACCES" error whilst trying to access layer code (node_modules)
I have a Lambda function in AWS, written in NodeJS. I created Terraform resources for this build. Everything seems to be deployed successfully, however when running the code it fails for permissions.
Terraform resources:
resource "null_resource" "zip_pupeteer_layer" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    working_dir = path.module
    command     = "chmod +x ./scripts/zip-pupeteer-layer.sh"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    working_dir = path.module
    command     = "./scripts/zip-pupeteer-layer.sh"
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "pupeteer" {
  filename                 = "${path.module}/pupeteer-layer/layer.zip"
  layer_name               = "pupeteer-lambda-layer"
  description              = "Pupeteer Lambda Layer with @sparticuz/chromium"
  compatible_runtimes      = [local.screenshot_function_node_version]
  compatible_architectures = [local.screenshot_function_arch]

  depends_on = [null_resource.zip_pupeteer_layer]
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "screenshot" {
  function_name    = "${local.screenshot_function_name}-${var.environment}"
  role             = aws_iam_role.screenshot_function.arn
  handler          = "index.handler"
  runtime          = local.screenshot_function_node_version
  timeout          = 30
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.screenshot_function.output_base64sha256
  s3_bucket        = var.s3_bucket_id_lambda_storage
  s3_key           = aws_s3_object.screenshot_function.key
  memory_size      = 10240
  architectures    = [local.screenshot_function_arch]
  layers           = [aws_lambda_layer_version.pupeteer.arn]


  environment {
    variables = {
      LOGZIO_TOKEN_LAMBDA = "bbbb",
      DB_HOST             = "bbbb",
      DB_PORT             = bbbb,
      DB_USER             = "bbbb",
      DB_PASSWORD         = "bbbbbbb",
      DB_DATABASE         = "bbbbb"
    }
  }

  tags = merge(
    var.common_tags,
    {
      Name = "${var.project}-${local.screenshot_function_name}-Lambda"
    }
  )

  depends_on = [aws_cloudwatch_log_group.screenshot]
}

My zip-pupeteer-layer.sh script (as you can see I ran also chmod for the file but it does not seem to help so I'm not sure..):
mkdir -p pupeteer-layer/nodejs

cd pupeteer-layer/nodejs

npm init -y
npm install @sparticuz/chromium@109.0.1 puppeteer-core@19.6.3

chmod -R 777 node_modules

cd ..

zip -r layer.zip nodejs/ -x "nodejs/package.json" -x "nodejs/package-lock.json"

However, when running the Lambda, I get an error:
Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /opt/nodejs/node_modules/@sparticuz/chromium/bin EACCES TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md at onClose (/var/task/index.js:33174:14) at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:33168:16) at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28) at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:292:12) at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16) at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

As you can see I get EACCES error.

Your Lambda function has local write access to /tmp only.
